# Multiplicação e soma de inputs em um site

Tags: javascript, html

Estou construindo um site e necessito de uma ajuda: tenho 3 campos nesse site (input) e cada um representa um valor fixo (1.500, 250 e 500), gostaria de poder inserir nestes campos a quantidade de vezes que quero esse valor para que seja feita a soma e o resultado seja apresentado sem a necessidade de carregar a página:

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Orçamento</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class="titulo">Orçamento</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        Quantidade item 1 =
        <input type="number" name="campoUm" id=""> 
        x R$ <var id="valorUm">1500</var> = 
    </div>
    <div>
        Quantidade item 2 =
        <input type="number" name="campoDois" id="">
        x R$ <var id="valorDois">250</var> =
    </div>
    <div>
        Quantidade item 3 =
        <input type="number" name="campoTres" id=""> 
        x R$ <var id="valorTres">500</var> =
    </div>
    <div>
        Total =
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Conseguem me ajudar?

Comment: Tem como colocar o HTML desses campos?

Comment: Não ficou bom, mas executando dá pra ver visualmente melhor o que estou tentando fazer.. Mas a partir dai, não sei como salvar em variáveis pra poder fazer os cálculos. Usaria o valor do id/class/name para isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite.

Você pode utilizar jQuery, para facilitar o manuseio de alguns elementos do HTML.
Com todo o respeito, eu tomei a liberdade de ajustar algumas coisas no seu código. Veja por favor se o exemplo abaixo te ajuda de alguma forma.

> **Explicação**: Para cada campo onde o usuário digita o valor, eu criei duas funções no jQuery, uma para o evento keyUp(Depois que ele termina de pressionar alguma tecla) e outra é a função change(caso o usuário clique na seta pra cima ou pra baixo, que fica dentro do campo).
>   A ideia é que toda vez que é digitado algum valor em qualquer um dos três campos, o script está pegando o valor de todos os campos e multiplicando pelo valor fixo que está definido nas tags VAR. Por último, está somando todos os resultados das multiplicações e exibindo o valor total na tag **valorTotal**
>   Para te ajudar, caso você precise pegar o valor total da compra, existe um campo **input type=hidden** com o **ID** e **name** igual a valorTotalCompra, caso você envie esse valor para uma outra página que irá processar o pagamento

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Orçamento</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1 class="titulo">Orçamento</h1>
</div>
<div>
    Quantidade item 1 =
    <input type="number" name="campoUm" id="campoUm"> 
    x R$ <var id="valorUm">1500</var> = <var id="resultado1"></var>
</div>
<div>
    Quantidade item 2 =
    <input type="number" name="campoDois" id="campoDois">
    x R$ <var id="valorDois">250</var> = <var id="resultado2"></var>
</div>
<div>
    Quantidade item 3 =
    <input type="number" name="campoTres" id="campoTres"> 
    x R$ <var id="valorTres">500</var> = <var id="resultado3"></var>
</div>
<div>
    Total = <var id="valorTotal"></var>
    <input type="hidden" name="valorTotalCompra" id="valorTotalCompra" value="" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //exemplo utilizando jQuery
        $(document).on('keyup','#campoUm',function(){
            let total1 = $('#'+this.id+'').val() * $('#valorUm').text();
            let total2 = $('#campoDois').val() * $('#valorDois').text();
            let total3 = $('#campoTres').val() * $('#valorTres').text();
            let valorTotal = total1 + total2 + total3;
            $('#resultado1').empty();
            $('#resultado1').html('R$ '+total1);
            $('#valorTotal').empty();
            $('#valorTotal').html('R$ '+valorTotal);
            $('#valorTotalCompra').val('');
            $('#valorTotalCompra').val(valorTotal);
        });

        $(document).on('change','#campoUm',function(){
            let total1 = $('#'+this.id+'').val() * $('#valorUm').text();
            let total2 = $('#campoDois').val() * $('#valorDois').text();
            let total3 = $('#campoTres').val() * $('#valorTres').text();
            let valorTotal = total1 + total2 + total3;
            $('#resultado1').empty();
            $('#resultado1').html('R$ '+total1);
            $('#valorTotal').empty();
            $('#valorTotal').html('R$ '+valorTotal);
            $('#valorTotalCompra').val('');
            $('#valorTotalCompra').val(valorTotal);
        });

        $(document).on('keyup','#campoDois',function(){
            let total2 = $('#'+this.id+'').val() * $('#valorDois').text();
            let total1 = $('#campoUm').val() * $('#valorUm').text();
            let total3 = $('#campoTres').val() * $('#valorTres').text();
            let valorTotal = total1 + total2 + total3;
            $('#resultado2').empty();
            $('#resultado2').html('R$ '+total2);
            $('#valorTotal').empty();
            $('#valorTotal').html('R$ '+valorTotal);
            $('#valorTotalCompra').val('');
            $('#valorTotalCompra').val(valorTotal);
        });

        $(document).on('change','#campoDois',function(){
            let total2 = $('#'+this.id+'').val() * $('#valorDois').text();
            let total1 = $('#campoUm').val() * $('#valorUm').text();
            let total3 = $('#campoTres').val() * $('#valorTres').text();
            let valorTotal = total1 + total2 + total3;
            $('#resultado2').empty();
            $('#resultado2').html('R$ '+total2);
            $('#valorTotal').empty();
            $('#valorTotal').html('R$ '+valorTotal);
            $('#valorTotalCompra').val('');
            $('#valorTotalCompra').val(valorTotal);
        });

        $(document).on('keyup','#campoTres',function(){
            let total3 = $('#'+this.id+'').val() * $('#valorTres').text();
            let total1 = $('#campoUm').val() * $('#valorUm').text();
            let total2 = $('#campoDois').val() * $('#valorDois').text();
            let valorTotal = total1 + total2 + total3;
            $('#resultado3').empty();
            $('#resultado3').html('R$ '+total2);
            $('#valorTotal').empty();
            $('#valorTotal').html('R$ '+valorTotal);
            $('#valorTotalCompra').val('');
            $('#valorTotalCompra').val(valorTotal);
        });

        $(document).on('change','#campoTres',function(){
            let total3 = $('#'+this.id+'').val() * $('#valorTres').text();
            let total1 = $('#campoUm').val() * $('#valorUm').text();
            let total2 = $('#campoDois').val() * $('#valorDois').text();
            let valorTotal = total1 + total2 + total3;
            $('#resultado3').empty();
            $('#resultado3').html('R$ '+total2);
            $('#valorTotal').empty();
            $('#valorTotal').html('R$ '+valorTotal);
            $('#valorTotalCompra').val('');
            $('#valorTotalCompra').val(valorTotal);
        });

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível pegar o valor das variáveis utilizando `javascript`, seja pelo `id`, `name` ou `class`, sendo que as duas ultimas opções, podem retornar 1 `array` já que na tela podem ter mais de 1 item com o mesmo nome ou classe.

No exemplo que criei peguei os itens pelo `id`, após isso fiz uma checagem se eles são numéricos e, caso não sejam, atribui o valor 0 para eles. Após isso fiz o calculo e por fim atribui o valores do calculo na tela através do elemento html `<span>`(para isso dei 1 `id` para cada).

Para que o calculo fosse feito cada vez que o valor dos `inputs` fossem alterados, joguei o código em uma `function` e chamo essa `function` no evento `onchange`, ou seja, toda vez que o valor for alterado:

```js
    function somaTudo(){

        var valorUm = parseInt(document.getElementById("campoUm").value)
        var valorDois = parseInt(document.getElementById("campoDois").value)
        var valorTres = parseInt(document.getElementById("campoTres").value)
        
        if(isNaN(valorUm))
        valorUm = 0

        if(isNaN(valorDois))
        valorDois = 0

        if(isNaN(valorTres))
        valorTres = 0

        var TotalUm = (valorUm * 1500);
        var TotalDois = (valorDois * 250);
        var TotalTres = (valorTres * 500);

        document.getElementById("TotalCampoUm").innerHTML= TotalUm;
        document.getElementById("TotalCampoDois").innerHTML = TotalDois;
        document.getElementById("TotalCampoTres").innerHTML = TotalTres;
        document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML = (TotalUm + TotalDois + TotalTres);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Orçamento</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class="titulo">Orçamento</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        Quantidade item 1 =
        <input onchange="somaTudo()" type="number" min="0" name="campoUm" id="campoUm"> 
        x R$ <var id="valorUm">1500</var> = <span id="TotalCampoUm"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        Quantidade item 2 =
        <input onchange="somaTudo()" type="number" min="0" name="campoDois" id="campoDois">
        x R$ <var id="valorDois">250</var> =<span id="TotalCampoDois"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        Quantidade item 3 =
        <input onchange="somaTudo()" type="number" min="0" name="campoTres" id="campoTres"> 
        x R$ <var id="valorTres">500</var> =<span id="TotalCampoTres"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        Total = <span id="Total"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma prática e que funciona em tempo real é criando eventos aos `inputs` que vai atualizando o valor à medida em que se vai alterando os campos. Não necessita de `id`s.

Para isso coloquei a tag `<var id="total"></var>` para receber o valor da soma:

```js
var qtd = document.body.querySelectorAll("input[type='number']");
for(var x=0; x<qtd.length; x++){
   qtd[x].addEventListener("input", function(){
      var vals = document.body.querySelectorAll("var[id*='valor']");
      var soma = 0;
      
      for(var y=0; y<vals.length; y++){
         soma += parseFloat(vals[y].textContent)*vals[y].parentNode.querySelector("input").value;
      }

      if(!isNaN(soma)) document.body.querySelector("#total").textContent = soma;
   });
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h1 class="titulo">Orçamento</h1>
</div>
<div>
   Quantidade item 1 =
   <input type="number" name="campoUm">
   x R$ <var id="valorUm">1500</var> = 
</div>
<div>
   Quantidade item 2 =
   <input type="number" name="campoDois">
   x R$ <var id="valorDois">250</var> =
</div>
<div>
   Quantidade item 3 =
   <input type="number" name="campoTres">
   x R$ <var id="valorTres">500</var> =
</div>
<div>
   Total = <var id="total"></var>
</div>
```